# How to remove white space around a saved image in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried all the suggested comments to remove the white space around a saved image in matplotlib but it didn't work for me. Actually, I cannot see the white frame around the image but when loading the image, there are white color values in the matrix so it does exist. I appreciate if any one can address this issue. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## -----------------------Initialize----------------------- 
pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100

coord = [[-150,-200],[300,-200],[300,0],[150,200],[-150,200]]

# Set figure dimensions
fig = plt.figure(figsize=( pixels/my_dpi, pixels/my_dpi),facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  

plt.axes([0,0,1,1])

rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
polygon = plt.Polygon(coord,color='w')
plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)

plt.axis('off')
plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
plt.axis('scaled')

plt.savefig('figure/%d.jpg',bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0,dpi=my_dpi)
```

Comment: Remove `bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0`. Take any of the existing answers that don't use those settings. (There should be comments below those saying that they actually work).

Comment: Removing those parameters still leads to the same resulting image.

Comment: Forgot to say, also `plt.axis('scaled')` needs to be removed. Else it will rescale the axis and add some padding back.

Comment: Thank you so much William. It worked perfectly.